# How to fix 'Bad file descriptor' after implementing here-string redirection in my own shell

Tags: c, linux, shell

I'm working on my own shell bit by bit and arrived at implementing I/O redirection functionalities. I've finished implementing `>`, `<` and `>>`. I'm stuck at implementing `<<<`.

My tried implementation for `<<<` is quite simple conceptually. Make a file named herestring, write the string in the file, set the file descriptor as STDIN_IN, execute the command and later delete the file.

The file's purpose is to basically store the string.
The file is being created and deleted successfully. Even the writing of the string inside the file is working. However when I execute the following in my own shell:

```
cat <<< Hello,world!
```

Actual results:

```
cat: -: Bad file descriptor
```

Expected:

```
Hello,world!
```

It's really weird because I've basically re-used the implementation of the input redirection (`command < file`) and the only part that I added is the part that works. So I'm really at loss what I'm missing in my code.

If more code is needed let me know.

Comment: I'm somewhat sure I'm missing something within the snippet of code I posted though.

Comment: That may well be true, but to test proposed fixes or confirm theorized explanations (or rule out external factors!), we need a (short-as-possible) example we can actually run ourselves. That's not asking for *more* code; the "short-as-possible" criteria is critical... it *is*, however, asking for *self-contained* code. See also "Tricks for Trimming" at http://sscce.org/.

Comment: Why does your code run `wait` in both the parent and the child process? (Alternatively, if `commands()` never returns, `remove()` is never called.)

Comment: `strace` (particularly `strace -f`) should tell you exactly what your processes are doing.

Comment: @melpormene - commands() never returns but remove() does get executed eventually. No idea why.

Answer (score 2):

Acording to `man creat`, a call to `creat()` is equivalent to calling `open()` with flags equal to `O_CREAT|O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC`.

`O_CREAT` and `O_TRUNC` make sense in your case. `O_WRONLY` not so much.

I recommend to use `open()` with flags `O_CREAT|O_RDWR|O_TRUNC`

Other issues with the code you have shown: (This is not a complete list!!)

- No error checking on 'creat()' 'write()' and 'dup2()' !!
- You forgot to rewind your file descriptor
- You forgot to close `fd`
- Saving the here-string to a named file is recipe for problems with race conditions, 
  and may leave clutter in the file-system.

If you intend to save the here-string to a file, you should study the `O_TMPFLAG` on how to make anonymous files in the file system. Then you don't need to call `remove()`, the file will automatically be deleted when all its file-descriptors are closed.

Comment: I changed creat() to open() with the given flags as instructed. Now when I try cat <<< hello, it doesn't show 'cat: -: Bad file descriptor' but doesn't provide any output. Also, I couldn't find anything on google regarding O_TMPFLAG.

Comment: Did you rewind the file-descriptor? After writing to `fd` I would guess it points to end of file.

Comment: You will find the description of O_TMPFLAG in the man page for `open()`. But i think it is linux-specific.